# Latexmk, gnuplot and subfolder

Tags: gnuplot, latexmk

I tried to setup latexmk such that my gnuplot files are generated automatically. Here is what I've done:

Folder/file structure:

```
latexmkrc
foo.tex
graphics/plot.gp
```

latexmk:

```
add_cus_dep('gp', 'tex', 0, 'gp_to_tex');
sub gp_to_tex {
    system("gnuplot \"$_[0].gp\"");
}
```

foo.tex:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \input{graphics/plot.tex}
\end{figure}
```

plot.gp:

```
# Version: gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 0
set terminal cairolatex monochrome
set output "graphics/plot.tex"
set format "$%g$"
set sample 200
set xrange [-pi:pi]
set yrange [-1:1]
set xlabel "$x$"
set ylabel "$y=\sin(x)$"
plot sin(x) linewidth 4 dashtype 1
```

Unfortunately, it doesnt work and I dont know why. Does somebody know whats the problem?

Relevant output by latexmk:

```
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on foo.log.
Latexmk: Missing input file: 'graphics/plot.tex' from line
  '! LaTeX Error: File `graphics/plot.tex' not found.'
Rule 'cusdep gp tex graphics/plot': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'graphics/plot.gp'
   Non-existent destination files:
      'graphics/plot.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'cusdep gp tex graphics/plot'
------------
=== Creating rule for 'cusdep gp tex graphics/plot'
Latexmk: applying rule 'cusdep gp tex graphics/plot'...
For rule 'cusdep gp tex graphics/plot', running '&do_cusdep( gp_to_tex )' ...


^
"graphics/plot.gp", line 1: invalid command

Rule 'cusdep gp tex graphics/plot', function 'gp_to_tex'
   failed with return code = 256
```

Best Regards,
Philipp

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I'd assume gnuplot fails on the command line as well, correct? How was the .gp file created (maybe a problem with unicode or other character encoding)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint! My latexmk setup is correct but gnuplot failed due to the BOM character in the gnuplot file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the root cause was a gunplot file's character encoding.